# Create plus button as push at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

In `tableViewController` i want to create a plus push button at "run time" in `viewDidLoad` of `tableViewController` to trigger another view.

I tried it as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //
    // create Button in Navigation
    //

    self.VC_AddToDoItem = [[GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.VC_AddToDoItem animated:NO];

    UIBarButtonItem *bt_Plus = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self.VC_AddToDoItem action:@selector(add:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bt_Plus;
}
```

The result is that the table view is not displayed. Instead the view is displayed with link back to table view. If i press this link, table view is displayed. If i then press plus button then i get a crash.

What could be the problem?

**Update:**

I added the add method now in GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item. Crash is now gone. Method add is called. But i don't know what to do in this method to show the view, therefore this method is empty at the moment. If i press the "+" button, nothing happens. What call is necessary in add method to display view GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item?

Comment: What is wrong with using CamelCase? self.VC_AddToDoItem should be self.vcAddToDoItem and I assume it is a strong reference? However, the action add: could be in your view controller directly. Unless you have some very good reason to introduce some object that reacts on the button press.

Comment: The button is a push to a view controller. Therefore the reaction is given. I want that the view controller is triggering by using this push trigger. But it doesn't work. Tableview is not shown, instead view is shown what is not wished. After return to table view and then to press plus button (push), then i get a crash as follows:

Comment: You need to add the `add:` method to your `GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item` class. (Please use standard naming conventions. That's hard to read).

Comment: add: method exists in GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item: - (IBAction)add:(id) push; But it doesn't work, he cannot find it at runtime

Comment: If it isn't there at runtime then the method doesn't exist. Update your question with the `add:` method from your `GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item` class. Make sure the `add:` method is from inside the `@implementation GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item` and not some other similarly named class.

Comment: BTW - is it possible the crash log is from before the `add:` method was actually added to your code. Your question originally didn't indicate a crash. If the `add:` method was still missing, it would crash every time.

Comment: add: method exists in GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item: - (IBAction)add:(id) push; It is called now. I don't know what to do in that method, because i only want to open the view. Crash is now gone, but view is not displayed. What i have to do in add method to display the view?

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen when the user presses the button? I would say that you schould do exactly that in add: method.

Comment: @Klecker: you are right, and i don't know what to do when i want to display the view GRF_VC_Add_To_Do_Item. Which method i have to use for that?

Comment: Think about what is necessary to transition from one view to another... If you segue using a Storyboard or transition the view in code, what is required to make this occur? A destination view controller? A custom `UIStoryboardSegue`? An overridden `prepare` method for your custom `UIStoryboardSegue`? Maybe a `prepareForSegue` method to prepare your current and destination view controllers?